# Update regular expression to only allow single spaces

Tags: c#, regex

How can I update my regular expression so that only single spaces are allowed? (In other words, `"aaa  2"` and `"aaa 3  "` should also return false.)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] items = new string[]
                {
                    "aaa0", "aaa 1", "aaa  2", "aaa 3  ", "aaa 1%", "youi_yuiuyu123"
                };

            foreach (string s in items)
            {
                string regEx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+$";
                Match match = Regex.Match(s, regEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                Console.WriteLine(match.Success);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+| )$` https://regex101.com/r/Z534al/1

Comment: Is `"a b c"` a valid match or not? In other words, do you want the string to only ever contain one space character or just prevent multiple consecutive space characters?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Check the edit (some spaces were not visible). I don't think that's what the OP is after.

Comment: @41686d6564 You are right, then I think something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$` $ https://regex101.com/r/bbrCsK/1

Comment: Yes, "a b c" would be a valid match. So, in summary: After each phrase of 'A-Z_', just one single space is allowed. This would make 'a b_ c' valid and 'a b_  c' (two spaces after the _) invalid. (Preferably, it may not end with a space as well, like 'a b c '.)

Comment: @RandyWink Then the pattern in Thefourthbird's last comment is what you need.

Comment: Can it start with a single space?

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks! (I only have to add an _ to the AZ-phrases.):
string regEx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$";